# Android App Layout Problem

Tags: bug, android-app

I have the stackoverflow app installed on my Galaxy Tab 3.
Every time I open a question, no matter from which stack site, I receive a layout error, which makes the app unusable.

[image]

Comment: Yes, seems to be the same problem. I am sorry, my bad.

Comment: @M0rgenstern in which case, you can accept the duplicate by clicking the big blue `Yes that solved my problem` button at the top of the question :)